# How can I make networking work in my WinCE app without launching IE first?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, networking, windows-ce

I have a simple WinCE network application (in C, Win32 APIs). I find that networking doesn't seem to work unless I launch IE (or another network app) first. I assume that IE is setting up my network interface in some way.

How can I do this for myself?

Might I need to display a list of available interfaces to the user (eg. WiFi/Ethernet/3G)?

Thanks.

Comment: Use the WinInet range of functions to open connection, send requests and stuff. You can also specify callback functions.

Answer (score 2):

All I know is that Internet Explorer uses [WinInet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383630(VS.85).aspx) (wininet.dll) for its networking, and you can too. WinInet is a MS API for working with http and ftp protocols. Many of the settings on the "Internet Options" control panel applet are actually WinInet settings (e.g. for dealing with cookies, setting up proxies on LANs, and autodial on dial-up networks). I'm 99% sure that anything that IE can do, you can do yourself using the API.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer might be

```
InternetAttemptConnect
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383996(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

If by "network application" you mean sockets, then WinCE definitely does not require IE to launch for that to work. You'll need to provide more specifics about what you're trying to do for a better answer than that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to establish a network connection first.  You can automate the process using the connection manager API:

[Connection Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb840031.aspx)

The user can also raise a data connection manually.